# How to describe the sound of the English language as spoken by someone with Asperger's Syndrome?

Tags: pronunciation, phrase-requests

I've heard many people say that individuals with Asperger's Syndrome seem to have a distinctive way of speaking the English language.

I've heard descriptions such as "The cadence of the words is different", but I've been wondering if there is a more general way of describing this difference.

Comment: Sufferers often speak in a *monotone* (i.e. - a "flat" voice with little cadence at all).

Comment: Cadence as in `tone` or as in `rhythm`?

Comment: Not an answerable question - there are many degrees of Aspergers, and a variety of different speech impediments.

Comment: Not a question about how English is pronounced. Marked speech differences associated with Asperger's Syndrome are language neutral.

Answer (score 3):

The [NIH](http://www.ninds.nih.gov/disorders/asperger/detail_asperger.htm) describes it as "speaking in an overly formal manner or in a monotone:"

> Children with AS want to know everything about their topic of interest
>   and their conversations with others will be about little else.  Their
>   expertise, high level of vocabulary, and **formal speech patterns**
>   make them seem like little professors.
>
> Their speech may be marked by a lack of rhythm, an odd inflection, or
>   a monotone pitch.